# Flow rate and circulation

Tags: vector-fields

This picture from Thomas Calculus 13th Edition Page 981 before the discussion on Green's theorem:

[image]

$\mathrm{F}$ is the velocity field. I can't understand how the flow rate through the bottom edge is: $\mathrm{{F}\cdot \hat{i} \Delta x}$
 which has units of $m^2 s^{-1}$. It doesn't make physical sense to me. Could anyone explain that?

Answer (score 1):

Say, you have some conserved (or not) quantity with the dimension $\mathrm{Q}$. It can be amount of drug ($\mathrm Q=\mathrm{mol}$), energy ($\mathrm Q=\mathrm J$), it doesn't matter. Then in 2D you can introduce the density $\rho$ of the quantity with $[\rho]=\mathrm Q/\mathrm m^2$. To find the amount of quantity in some region, you need to integrate the density over this region.

Now if you multiply the density by velocity field, you will get a flow $\vec F$:
$$[\vec F]=[\rho\vec v]=\frac{\mathrm Q}{\mathrm m^2}\frac{\mathrm m}{\mathrm s} = \frac{\mathrm Q}{\mathrm{m\cdot s}}.$$

Thus, by multiplying $\vec F\cdot \vec i\Delta x$, you will get the dimension of $\mathrm Q/\mathrm s$, which reads “the amount of $\mathrm Q$ that passes through the boundary $\Delta x$ in 1 second”.

Finally, sometimes we are interested in the velocity field itself so we choose entity $\mathrm Q$ to be the unit of scalar density: $\mathrm Q=m^2$, so ($[\rho]=1$).

Comment: Why does multiplying 2D density with velocity give Flow F?

Comment: That is the definition of the flow in physics.

Comment: How to physically interpret it?

Comment: That is the amount of entity that passes through the segment of unit length perpendicular to the flow in 1 second.

Comment: OK, and I didn't get this part: "Finally, sometimes we are interested in the velocity field itself  so we choose entity Q to be the unit of scalar density". Why?

Comment: I don't get your question, sorry.

Comment: If you let Q be m^2 , then that means "The amount of m^2 that passes through the boundary $\Delta x$ in 1 second"...Which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Why? Consider the square grid. Let the flow $F$ [transform this grid](https://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/Bitmaps/variable%20scale%20change.gif), so each point $\vec p$ will move to $\vec p+\vec F\,dt$. Then, your entitiy is the area of initial grid, and you are asking how much of this area passes through a given segment.